# How to type custom `preload` method for React.lazy components?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-suspense

When trying to implement a `preload()` method for `React.lazy()` components, a typical pattern looks something like,

```
const ReactLazyPreload = (importStatement) => {
  const Component = React.lazy(importStatement);
  Component.preload = importStatement; // Property 'preload' does not exist on type 'LazyExoticComponent<T>'.
  return Component;
};
```

which can later be used, eg,

```
const MyComponent = ReactLazyPreload(() => import("./MyComponent.tsx");
const onHover = () => { MyComponent.preload() };
```

However, the assignment on the 3rd line of the first snippet causes a TS error,

`Property 'preload' does not exist on type 'LazyExoticComponent<T>'.`

I've been playing around with `declare`, but have been unsuccessful in removing the error. What type should be used for the `preload()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript is trying to prevent you from making a mistake here.

Just because other people follow a convention doesn't make it a good one: in this case, it's not a safe one. **As a general rule, it's never safe to mutate things you don't own.**

While I can't find anything in the React codebase at the current version tag (`17.0.2`) that would seem to cause an issue with assigning something to the `preload` property of a lazy component, that doesn't mean that the React maintainers won't use this property in a subsequent release. If that happens, and you overwrite that property, then unpredictable behavior would arise.

Instead of mutating the component, just return the preload function alongside it:

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwCYFMBmBDArgG3hgZzgCUUMBjGAGjhwwC8BPAXzjSghDgHIozLuAbgBQoSLDgxGYFIgDCnSADsUSmABVpKGgBkGjAKIAPCDGDkF4CCrWt2nHnwowhw4SiPj4UmSX4w9JgAxZ2hGAB51OABeOAwlRgA+GLgACgBKGOSABQ4QYAIUcOR0bDwALjhLZVUNLUjE5kSRd09oby0qxWta3JQcCAwkdSwwHCKo2PiklIBtYTg4cm6bGErAwxMzCxXa8OqetU0ZBsSqBbgwPgGhoKVKjKy4ADcIYCRzgF0Wjy82LCUlGA1jgAHMUAF9AdVgB1YAwAAWfRuSDgkRS00SqWWVlW2QwiMqBBgUGASlB6Uq0N610Gw1G4waIl+7X+gLMIPBkKY1LUcMRyLpaMmcQSWMwlDClVIzg2IUlUAi6kSlK6uJp-TpIzGE2arT+aABQM5EI2vJg-KRtKGwoxYtSZLAWDWcGJpPJcAAPn5Zfp5TAwg1VebBUNtYzlYgLsslMS2KFFSlHtFkj4UBA0HBHc6YtFYtw3WTQdw4AB+LNWWAOpROmCZSrZmAZESLPgwLBQJRwWZ0JipCUBxXpGgDsLfYTMNzCAD007gAFpF0vlzO58YMOBxgA6GAEIxuFkSNNwdeblC5CBgIixBAXGAeF2F8kiZg-NoSVCYXDwQ3s4Fd08dXNNIEHvIwYGYSpAPGC8r0yW9WwhDsu3CJBgGeRJQIfZhwmnNCMJfKdZwXZdSNXOAAEElFMBEUCgc0dz3NxiKwQo4AAd3hBFLgJbiAyWXY1HKYQYzjWZoJQABGGgrk1IYJMkz4Ui5M1BItLjQyQcIJNgggsW4Ldpwk7h0haFi2M4xF4wVRg2WNe4ROsMSJIAJhk60kFcpTYhUqE1MtTTtKMDcdV0rFk2SMR2lSAyjOCs8TNM4QgA)

```ts
import {default as React, lazy} from 'react';
import type {ComponentType, LazyExoticComponent} from 'react';

export type ReactLazyFactory<T = any> = () => Promise<{default: ComponentType<T>}>;

export type ComponentPreloadTuple<T = any> = [
  component: LazyExoticComponent<ComponentType<T>>,
  preloadFn: () => void,
];

export function getLazyComponentWithPreload <T = any>(componentPath: string): ComponentPreloadTuple<T>;
export function getLazyComponentWithPreload <T = any>(factory: ReactLazyFactory<T>): ComponentPreloadTuple<T>;
export function getLazyComponentWithPreload <T = any>(input: string | ReactLazyFactory<T>): ComponentPreloadTuple<T> {
  const factory = () => typeof input === 'string' ? import(input) : input();
  return [lazy(factory), factory];
}


// ----------
// Example.tsx

export type ExampleProps = {
  text: string;
};

export default function ExampleComponent ({text}: ExampleProps) {
  return <div>{text}</div>;
}


// ----------
// AnotherComponent.tsx

// use with path to component:
const [Example1, preloadExample1] = getLazyComponentWithPreload<ExampleProps>('./Example');

// use with factory function:
const [Example2, preloadExample2] = getLazyComponentWithPreload<ExampleProps>(() => import('./Example'));
```

Comment: It pains me to provide an answer that has `any` in a generic, but it's the correct type for the current React type declaration files 

Answer (score 2):

```js
// extend lazy component with `preload` property
interface LazyPreload<Props>
  extends React.LazyExoticComponent<React.ComponentType<Props>> {
  preload: () => {};
}

function ReactLazyPreload<Props>(
  importStatement: () => Promise<{ default: React.ComponentType<Props> }>
) {
  // use Object.assign to set preload
  // otherwise it will complain that Component doesn't have preload
  const Component: LazyPreload<Props> = Object.assign(
    React.lazy(importStatement),
    {
      preload: importStatement,
    }
  );

  return Component;
}
```